# Numerically designing a periodic 1D curve  that maximizes an integral area objective and satisfies value, derivative, and frequency constraints

Tags: optimization, matlab, approximation, fourier-analysis

I need to write MATLAB program (or use an existing one) to obtain Fourier series coefficients. Let's say the series is going to approximate a 1D curve. The boundary conditions are:

- value of the curve's function in a few places
- curve's first derivative known in a few places
- maximum allowed value of curve's second derivative
- number of harmonics
- the value of curve's integral over a specified interval should be as big as possible <- optimization criterion.

All the functions and tools I've seen so far can obtain series coefficients in much more simple cases. Any hints will be helpful, especially:

- literature, articles with descriptions of useful methods
- hints on objective functions useful for Fourier Series
- info on useful MATLAB Tools

Comment: It seems the same question asked [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/45491-looking-for-hints-for-the-n-harmonic-cam-design).

Comment: @Jann - You might have better luck on here explaining how you are formulating your optimization problem and asking for specific advice on each bit.  I don't know of a general-purpose MATLAB tool that will solve this problem for you.

Answer (score 3):

Write your function as a linear combination of harmonics and treat the coefficients as variables. This gives a semi-infinite linear program. 
The Matlab optimization toolbox has a routine linprog to solve linear programs (LPs) only; so you need to discretize the curvature constraint.

Replace the curvature constraint by $N$ constraints evaluated at $N$ equidistant points, solve the LP, add more points close to the points where near-worst case curvature occurred, and repeat until the desired accuracy is reached.